# Get data from UIButton in viewForHeaderInSection sent to method in add Target

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uibutton

Updated to be more clear, sorry noob.

I setup a button to appear in a header in each section on a tableview, the button appears and calls the specified function, however I'd like to pass section data to the method that's called.

When I try to use the UIButton.tag or even assign the section title to the button's textLabel title it always comes back as nil (even when the section title shows properly).

I need to pass data to the function so I know what I'm dealing with (I want to use another view controller to add a new piece of data to the rows in that specific section).

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
var sectionsDictionary:NSDictionary = ["Fruits" : ["Apple", "Pear", "Plum","Orange","Kiwi","Banana","Grape"], "Veggies" : ["Celery", "Carrots", "Lettuce","Brocoli","Squash"]]

var sectionTitlesArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    sectionTitlesArray = Array(sectionsDictionary.allKeys)
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return sectionTitlesArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var headerFrame:CGRect = tableView.frame

    var title = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30))
    title.text = sectionTitlesArray.objectAtIndex(section) as? String

    var headBttn:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.ContactAdd) as UIButton
    headBttn.enabled = true
    headBttn.titleLabel?.text = title.text

    headBttn.addTarget(self, action: "showAddVC:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    var headerView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, headerFrame.size.width, headerFrame.size.height))
    headerView.addSubview(title)
    headerView.addSubview(headBttn)

    return headerView

}

func showAddVC(sender: UIButton!) {

    println(sender.titleLabel?.text)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    var headerFloat = CGFloat.abs(20)

    return headerFloat

}
```

Comment: So your button function is called? Where is your code for addRoom?

Comment: Sorry, it was really supposed to be showAddVC, fixed. I had a bunch of stuff in there but made a new project to make it easier to work with temporarily.

Comment: And your function gets called? Please be more specific and delete all the posted useless (to answer the question) code here.

Comment: Yes, the function gets called and executes the println() - but anything I call on the sender (the UIButton) shows up nil. I can't add a parameter to AddTarget, and I read I can't use a closure there either. I need to keep track of what section the button gets touched in.

Comment: made it even cleaner

Comment: Hmm i had a similar function in my code, and when ill try to print out the titlelabel, everything works fine. Try to set Sections to 1 and try again (maybe a problem with multiple Buttons?)

Comment: Setting the section to 1 still returns the println as nil - it's like it gets generated before the table is built, I'm not sure. I wish I could just pass a parameter to the method or do some house keeping inside a closure.

Answer (score 1):

Phew, got it, I was able to use .tag by just using indexOfObject and passing the object at index in section.

```
headBttn.tag = sectionTitlesArray.indexOfObject(sectionTitlesArray.objectAtIndex(section))
```

this gives .tag the index of where the button was pressed, which I can use later on. woohoo.